# In React, how to encapsulate logic in a Todo component?

Tags: reactjs, refactoring, encapsulation, react-component

In a Todo app made with **React**, like [this one](https://github.com/mdn/todo-react), we have a function `toggleTaskCompleted` in the `App` component which gets passed as a prop to each `Todo` component. This function can then be called in the Todo component when a button is clicked resp. a checkbox is toggled.

I wonder if we can move this logic entirely to the `Todo` component. For example, this is possible in **Svelte** and **Vue**. In Vue, we create a ref for the list (and in Svelte, a regular variable), loop through it to list all todos and pass the respective todo as a prop. When we change the todo in the `Todo` component (for example, mark it as complete), this change is automatically also seen by the parent `App` component. (Meanwhile, the approach by passing a function as a prop is also possible in Svelte and Vue.)

I prefer this approach much more, it is more encapsulated, and we have to write less code. So I wonder if we can do the same in React.

*Edit.* Actually, the list *is* updated in the `App` component. However, this does not effect a rerender, and also `useEffect`, depending on the list, won't notice this change. So my question is basically how to inform the component about this change (without writing too much code or even using external state mangement).

Comment: Do you need the task completion status at the `App` level? If not, completion status should be part of `Todo` component state, this way you could easily move the `toggleTaskCompleted` logic in `Todo` component.

Comment: Yes the list as a whole needs to be saved somewhere (in a database, say), including the info about completed todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would be better to use **React Context** in this case because you'll need to applay the `state` and the logic for your `Todos` in many components (like a navbar to track number of todos ...)    . In this case React Context is a way to manage state globally. So it  allow your components to access some global data (In your case your todos and the  function toggleTaskCompleted )  and  and re-render when that global data is changed . this is a simple [Demo](https://daveceddia.com/usecontext-hook/) how to use it